# Why I can reference to table being modified in SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am quite new to SQL, and I have a question about some basics:

As I understand while reading Gruber book, it is impossible to use table being modified now in "FROM" sentence as well as in subquery.
So, I have a table:

```
snum |sname  |city     |comm
----------------------------
1001 |Peel   |London   |0.12
1002 |Serres |San Jose |0.13
1003 |Axelrod|New York |0.1
1004 |Motika |London   |0.11
1007 |Rifkin |Barcelona|0.15
1100 |Bianco |San Jose |0.14
```

And a query:

```
INSERT INTO SalespeopleCopy(sname, city, comm)
SELECT sname, city, comm FROM SalespeopleCopy seconddata
WHERE seconddata.city >= (Select MAX(city) from SalespeopleCopy);
```

Table has changed after executing it:

```
snum |sname  |city     |comm
----------------------------
1001 |Peel   |London   |0.12
1002 |Serres |San Jose |0.13
1003 |Axelrod|New York |0.1
1004 |Motika |London   |0.11
1007 |Rifkin |Barcelona|0.15
1100 |Bianco |San Jose |0.14
1102 |Serres |San Jose |0.13 (new row)
1100 |Bianco |San Jose |0.14 (new row)
```

In the third row I reference to SalespeopleCopy table which is in "FROM" sentence. And SalespeopleCopy is being modified at the same time.

Is it a feature of SQLite(3) database? Or I don't understand the basics correctly?

About book i am reading
There is a table named "SJpeople"
We want to insert some rows to it. And we wand to check is a current row already exists in SJpeople table before inserting it.

**quote:**

"It would be better if you could somehow find out that these values were already inserted into the table, before you try to do it again, by adding another subquery (using operators like EXISTS, IN, <> ALL, and so on) to the predicate.
Unfortunately, in order to do this work, you will need to refer to the SJpeople table itself in the FROM clause of this new subquery, and, as we said earlier, you cannot refer to the table that is involved (in its entirety) in any subquery of the modification command."

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to include an excerpt from the book that you are basing your understanding upon. As you can see what you have tried works and it would also probably work, at least in principle, on other RDBMS's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the query you executed is:

```
INSERT INTO SalespeopleCopy(snum, sname, city, comm)
SELECT snum, sname, city, comm FROM SalespeopleCopy seconddata
WHERE seconddata.city >= (Select MAX(city) from SalespeopleCopy);
```

including the `snum` column, in't it?
by:

```
Select MAX(city) from SalespeopleCopy
```

you get:

```
San Jose
```

So by:

```
SELECT snum, sname, city, comm FROM SalespeopleCopy seconddata
WHERE seconddata.city >= (Select MAX(city) from SalespeopleCopy)
```

you get 2 rows:

```
1102 |Serres |San Jose |0.13
1100 |Bianco |San Jose |0.14
```

and these 2 rows are inserted to the table.
In the statement of your query, you reference the name of the table `SalespeopleCopy` 3 times. 
The 2nd reference is *aliased* to `seconddata`:

```
FROM SalespeopleCopy seconddata
```

you could also write it:

```
FROM SalespeopleCopy AS seconddata
```

so the table's name from which you want to `SELECT` rows will be from now on `seconddata` 
although it is the same table and so in the `WHERE` part:

```
WHERE seconddata.city >= ....
```

there is no confusion to which table's `city` you are referring to:

- the `city` column of the table where the rows are **inserted to** or
- the `city` column of the table where the rows are **selected from**

  This is not a feature of SQLite only, it is standard SQL

Comment: Thank you very much! So as I understand, when we use alias of a table, the table is not actually copied, but the SQL is executed this command is as if it were done. And in that case we can imagine that we modify only initial table, not copy.

Comment: No there is no copy, an alias is just another name for the same table (or column when needed) and it is very commonly used. In your case it is not necessary but it is a good practice.